# How can I make sure that each worker in gunicorn uses only one cpu core?

Tags: python, flask, pytorch, gunicorn, huggingface-transformers

I am running inference using a Huggingface transformer model for question answering.

I have exposed this as an API using flask and gunicorn (with multiple workers).

I have noticed that when a single request is issued, more than 1 CPU cores are being utilized.

Hence, when more than one request is issued concurrently, the response for each is taking much longer. For example, 1 request = 1.2 seconds whereas, 2 requests = getting both responses after 2 seconds.

It would be ideal if both requests took 1.2 seconds to be served.

This issue is occurring although I have more than one workers in gunicorn.

[In this article](https://blog.roblox.com/2020/05/scaled-bert-serve-1-billion-daily-requests-cpus/), they address the issue by thread tuning in PyTorch, they offer a solution by adding this line to their code:
`torch.set_num_threads(1)`

It seems that this is supposed to ensure that each worker uses exactly one cpu core and make sure they are not competing for the same resources.

I have incorporated this into my code. However, the problem still seems to persist.

Hence, I suspect that this is due to some configuration in gunicorn.

The Flask app is defined in the file QA_transformer.py and this is what I use to start gunicorn:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 QA_transformer:app --workers 3
```

Is there something that should be added or changed?
How can I make sure that each worker uses only one CPU core?
Or does the `torch.set_num_threads(1)` not work as expected for 'pipeline' in the transformers library from Huggingface?

PS. I am using a machine with 4 CPU cores.

Comment: Python threading is not true threading because of [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), so if you want to  use multiple CPU cores you need to use multiprocessing instead

Comment: i don't think gunicorn has such worker cpu affinity support